# How to make carousel mobile responsive and have the picture fit accdg. to carousel size

Tags: html, css, carousel

This is my code. The carousel works but I need it to be mobile responsive and the images fit according to the carousel size no matter the size of the image. Your help is gladly appreciated.

So first how to make the carousel mobile responsive. Second how to make the images fit the carousel container no matter what the image size is.

```html
<?php 
  session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.item img {
  width:100%
}
.carousel-inner{
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>

<div class="container" style=" width:100%; height: 800px;">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
   
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style=" width:100%; height: 800px !important;">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="1.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="2.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="3.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

       <div class="item">
        <img src="4.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>




    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add img-responsive class to your image to make responsive its for bootstrap 3 and bootstrap img-fluid is the class name.